# Adding a Tailwindcss class name using a Vue.js computed method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, tailwind-css

I am trying to use some methods and functions to generate a predefined tailwind class name for a component. The class name works fine as a static form. but when I use the computed method and my functions there wouldn't be any style for the component.

```js
const getClass = computed(()=>{
  return useColorAsBackgroundClass(props.color, props.shade)
})
```

This is the function that generates a string of the form "-bg--l-green-50" which is completely acceptable by static classing

```html
<div class="-bg--l-green-50"></div> <!-- works fine --!>
```

I tried using the code as `v-bind()` inside the `var()` method for css. I also tried `v-bind()` alone by adding var() for the returned text of the computed.

Also

```js
  <button :class="{getClass}" type="button">
    hi
  </button>
```

doesn't work, not {} or [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have the entire class in a `prop` (ensuring the file that contains the `component` *usage* is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration):

  ```js
  <component color-class="-bg--l-green-50" …>
  ```

  ```js
  <button :class="colorClass">
  ```
- Have a dictionary for `color` and `shade` to Tailwind class names (ensuring the file that the dictionary is defined is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration):

  ```js
  const DICTIONARY = {
    'l-green': {
      50: '-bg--l-green-50',
      60: '-bg--l-green-60',
      70: '-bg--l-green-70',
      80: '-bg--l-green-80',
      // …
    }
  }
  const useColorAsBackgroundClass = (color, shade) => {
    // …
    return DICTIONARY[color][shade];
  }
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^-bg--l-(green|red|blue)-\d+$/ },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```